# unchecked call to setRowFilter(RowFilter<? super M,? super I>) DefaultRowSorter

Tags: java, warnings, tablerowsorter

Al compilar mi proyecto con **Clean and build**, me encuentro con estos **warnings**:

```
linea 546: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setRowFilter(RowFilter<? super M,? super I>) as a member of the raw type DefaultRowSorter
        TRSFiltro.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textfield_buscar.getText(), columna));
  where M,I are type-variables:
    M extends Object declared in class DefaultRowSorter
    I extends Object declared in class DefaultRowSorter
linea 558: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to TableRowSorter(M) as a member of the raw type TableRowSorter
        TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter(tabla_clientes.getModel());
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends TableModel declared in class TableRowSorter
linea 559: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method setRowSorter in class JTable is applied to given types
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found: TableRowSorter
linea 559: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found:    TableRowSorter
4 warnings
```

Supongo que el problema se debe a que no he usado una clase para tipos genéricos sin indicarle el tipo de dato pero ni asignando el tipo de dato consigo evitar el **warning**.

Al crear la **tabla/model**:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

//Ordenar las filas por la primera columna DNI.
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);
//Ordenar por titulo las columnas.
tabla_clientes.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Código referente al **TRSFiltro**:

```
    private TableRowSorter TRSFiltro;

    public void filtrar_dni() {
        int columna = 0; //Es la fila del DNI.
        TRSFiltro.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textfield_buscar.getText(), columna));
    }

    private void textfield_buscarKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        textfield_buscar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e){
            String texto = (textfield_buscar.getText());
            textfield_buscar.setText(texto);
            filtrar_dni();
        }
        });

        TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter(tabla_clientes.getModel());
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te faltan los parámetros en estos dos lugares?

```
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> TRSFiltro;
```

y después cuando inicializas la variable:

```
TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter<>(tabla_clientes.getModel()); // notá el rombo
```

Comment: El código de la inicialización de la variable me resulta incorrecto. Error: The type of <M> TableRowSorter is erroneous.

Comment: De que forma te resulta incorrecto. Estas usando una versión anterior a java 8?

Comment: Estoy utilizando java 1.8.0_251

Comment: Que error te marca? En caso de que tengas el java level seteado a una version anterior reemplazalo por: `TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(tabla_clientes.getModel());`

Comment: Así fue... Tuve que hacerle un casting pero funciona correctamente.